# Is my proof showing $Q$ is non-measurable complete?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing

Is my proof valid or complete? if not, what is missing??

Define $R$ on $[0, 1)$. When $x,y\in
[0, 1)$, $xRy \iff y-x$ is a rational number. Then $R$   is an equivalence
relation. Let $Q$ be the set of rational numbers in [0; 1). Let $C$ be the set of all equivalence class in $[0,1)$.

I attempts to proof that $Q$ is non-measurable. I am trying to show that if a real number is chosen from $[0,1)$ randomly, then $Pr(Q)$ is undefined.

(i) Note that $C$ is a partition of $[0, 1)$,equivalently saying that $Pr(\cup_{A\in C})= 1.$

(ii) Also there is a cyclic shifting function $f_s:Q\to A$ for all $A\in C$,
so $Pr(A) = Pr(Q)$ for all $A\in C$.(I have proved it before, and also $f_s$ is a bijective function)

(iii) If $Pr(Q) = 0$, then $Pr(\cup_{A\in C}) =\sum_{A\in C} Pr(A) = 0$, contradicting
$Pr(\cup_{A\in C}) = 1. If Pr(Q) > 0$, then $Pr(\cup_{A\in C}) =
\sum_{A\in C} Pr(A)=
\infty$, contradicting $Pr(\cup_{A\in C}) = 1$.

(iv) Therefore $Pr(Q)$ is undefine

Comment: What does $\sum_{A \in C}$ mean? Recall that $\Pr$ is only _countably_ additive, while $C$ is _uncountable_.

Comment: But aren't countable sets measurable, if singletons are :-). $Q$ is countable, so...

Answer (score 3):

$\Bbb Q$ is measurable because every singleton is measurable, and $\Bbb Q$ is the countable union of singletons.

If one picks $V$ to be a set of representatives for $R$, that is for every $R$-equivalence class $X$, $V\cap X$ is a singleton; then $V$ is non-measurable.

Of course, if you are working with something other than the Lebesgue measure, my answer is not going to be helpful.